# Filter Woocommerce archive pages with product attribute values by default

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, archive, taxonomy

I would like products archive pages to display products corresponding to a specific attribute value by default.

**Example**
Attribute: pa_condition
Terms: New, Used, Closeout

I would like to see only new products when opening the shop.

But there are 2 languages. So I guess, the condition should apply to the attribute id.

How this can be done?

Comment: What have you tried, what is your code? From what you have written it's not clear where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** You can try this hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $tax_query;

    // Define HERE the product attribute and the terms
    $taxonomy = 'pa_condition';
    $terms = array( 'New', 'Used', 'Closeout' ); // Term names

    // Add your criteria
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'name', // Or 'slug' or 'term_id'
        'terms'    => $terms,
    );
    return $tax_query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

But I am not sure about the translations of the terms, so you should be oblige to add them in a second `$tax_query[]` array in the query for that translated terms…

---

Official reference: [WP_Query ~ Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: It returns "no product corresponding to selected criteria". I have just removed "Define HERE the product attribute and the terms". I am not sure if I have to leave all the terms in the array or just 'New'. I am not sure if if I have to replace 'names' in the 'field' =>

Comment: I keep 'field'    => 'names', exactly like this ? or should I replace names with New ?

Comment: http://windspirit.gbwebmedia.com/onlinestore/windsurf/windsurf-boards/ : No products were found matching your selection.

Comment: what I changed in your code : $terms = array( 'new', 'used', 'distributors' ); // Term names and 'field'    => 'new',

Comment: Sorry @Gaël … I have Tested, maid some little changes… Now this is working as expected. Try it. Thanks